# Checkstyle "Method Not Designed For Extension" error being incorrectly issued?

Tags: java, checkstyle

I'm using Checkstyle and am getting an error about this method:

```
public final String getAdmitCodeStatus() {
    return admitCodeStatus;
}
```

Here's the error I get:

> Method 'getAdmitCodeStatus' is not designed for extension - needs to be abstract, final, or empty.

How is that method not compliant? Is there something I'm doing wrong that Checkstyle would bark at me about this method?

Comment: Do you have another instance of `getAdmitCodeStatus` that would be in violation of that rule? For example, is there a base class that implements that method with a non-empty body?

Comment: Can you make the class as final to see if it goes away (if your class can indeed be made final)?

Comment: @Chris: Good idea, but I do not. I just did a search to make sure and I have no other methods that share this name.

Comment: @CoolBeans: Unfortunately, I can not make this class either final or abstract. I do instantiate the class as is and, in some cases, extend it and instantiate the subclass.

Comment: Did you get your question answered?

Answer (score 33):

It looks to be caused by the `DesignForExtension` rule.  According to [the documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#DesignForExtension):

> Checks that classes are designed for extension. More specifically, it
>   enforces a programming style where superclasses provide empty "hooks"
>   that can be implemented by subclasses.
>
> The exact rule is that nonprivate, nonstatic methods of classes that
>   can be subclassed must either be
>
> ```
> abstract or
> final or
> have an empty implementation
> ```
>
> Rationale: This API design style protects superclasses against beeing
>   broken by subclasses. The downside is that subclasses are limited in
>   their flexibility, in particular they cannot prevent execution of code
>   in the superclass, but that also means that subclasses cannot corrupt
>   the state of the superclass by forgetting to call the super method.

Source: http://sonar.15.n6.nabble.com/design-for-extension-rule-tp3200037p3200043.html

But since your method has a `final` modifier, I'd say you found a bug and might want to log a bug report.
https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues

Comment: @Chris You are right. I've modified my answer to indicate that it doesn't really answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it looks like what on the earth kind of programming style is this...
This just checks whether you are planing methods to be inherited or not...and then you can declare them `final,abstract or empty implementation.`
Then you declare it final... ;)
Either the class can be final or the methods individual depending on the requirement scenario.

Comment: this doesn't seem to answer the question. the OP is declaring his method final, which would seem to satisfy the rule, he's looking for an explanation of why he still gets the error.

Comment: It's My Bad Nathan !
I didn't read it properly.
I am also new here so i beg your pardon and will take more care while posting from now.
Thanks ! :)

Comment: don't worry about it, misreading questions is very easy to do, I do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I think this check is useful and most of the times the warning is justified. Sometimes it is not appropriate and then I ignore it.