# Keeping a value class non-final for possible future extensibility

Tags: java, effective-java

I am creating a very simple class called Catalog.  It will be an immutable class and have an id and name field.

Out of habit, since I am not going to explicitly document this thing for extensibility, I put the final modifier on the class.  However I'm wondering that since this is such a simple value class, would it hurt to leave the final modifier off in case someone in the future decides they could use it?

Comment: Is this class part of a public API, and used by code on which you have no control? If so, then you should definitely think if it makes sense or not to extend the class. If not, then leave it final, and ask yourself if it's a good idea to make it non-final when you feel the need to extend the class.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218744/good-reasons-to-prohibit-inheritance-in-java. The top answer has a good summary for extensibility.

Comment: If the [reasons are known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218744/good-reasons-to-prohibit-inheritance-in-java), there is no need to discuss it. That can only end in opinion based positings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it is good practice to make simple value types `final`.  If you want to guarantee immutability, you actually *have to* do so.  That's also (partially) why `String`, `Integer`, etc are all `final`.

If your class is not `final`, somebody could extend it by adding methods that mutate it.  A client who is passed an instance of the extended type (upcasted to your type) would falsely believe to deal with an immutable object when it actually isn't.

In my own code, I actually go a little further and make almost any class `final` if I didn't design it with extensibility explicitly in mind.  If you want to support extension, consider providing an abstract class or an interface.  This is also in line with the [*abstract, final or empty*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780099/checkstyle-method-not-designed-for-extension-error-being-incorrectly-issued) rule for methods.

**Update:** Why does immutability require a class to be `final`?  Of course, there are other ways to ensure a particular *attribute* of an object is not changed.

Consider for example a `RGBColor` class with three attributes `red`, `green` and `blue` of type `byte`.  We make all three `final` and set them in the constructor once for all time.  (We can additionally make them `private` and add appropriate getter methods but that's not important for the sake of this discussion.)  Of course, we override the `equals` method to return `true` if and only if the compared object is an instance of `RGBColor` with the same `red`, `green` and `blue` values.

This looks innocent but what if somebody decides to extend our class to a `RGBAColor` class by adding an `alpha` attribute?  Naturally, the extender would desire to override `equals` to also take into account the `alpha` value.  Suppose our extender also isn't very careful about immutability and thus makes `alpha` non-`final` and supplies a setter for it.

Now, if we are given an object of type `RGBColor`, we cannot safely assume that if it compared equal to another one, it will still do so a minute from now.  We could have prevented this (particular problem) by also declaring `equals` as `final` in our `RGBColor` class.  But then, we could have equally well made the entire class `final` because extending a value type without the possibility to extend the notion of equality is close to useless.  (Thre are other problems with overriding `equals` such as it not being symmetric.  I generally feel not too comfortable about it.)

Comment: So even though my fields are private, a subclass could overwrite those values?  I don't see how immutability is broken for the actual values.  However I see that overridding one of the super class's method could return a value other than the one set in the constructor so that from a clients point of view the class is mutable.  Can you elaborate please.

Answer (score 2):

You said "it will be immutable", so make it final to ensure the class cannot be overridden

Answer (score 1):

Yes it could hurt to leave off the final modifier. By omitting it the people who use your class can't trust that it's immutable, and therefore they can't take advantage of the benefits of immutable objects, for example thread safety.